# How to draw a rectangle in HTML which can depict a time range?

Tags: html, css

I want to be able to draw a rectangle in HTML giving me different time ranges and I need to show the ranges with different colors.

Answer (score 0):

I hope I understand you correctly. Do you mean like in this snippet(?):

```html
<fieldset>
    <legend style="background-color:#480;color:#fff">Appointment details</legend>

    <label for="appt-time">Time:</label>
    <input type="time" id="appt-time" min="9:00" max="18:00" value="09:30" required />
    <br>
    <span style="color:#999">Office hours: 09:00 to 18:00</span>
    
    <br><br>
    
    <label for="doctor">Doctor:</label>
    <select id="doctor">
        <option value="strange">Strange</option>
        <option value="moreau">Moreau</option>
        <option value="watson">Phibes</option>
    </select>
    
</fieldset>
```

You need only to write:

```html
<input type="time" value="09:30"/><br><br>

<b>Or with seconds:</b><br>
<input type="time" value="09:30:00" step="15"/>
```

This is a HTML5 `<input>` element of type `time` which creates input fields designed to let the user easily enter a time (hours and minutes, and optionally seconds).

See: **[Documentation from `<input>` element of type `time`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/time)**.

Answer (score -1):

To create a rectangle with HTML and CSS, you can create and then style a div.

HTML

```
<div id="rectangle">I'm a Rectangle.</div>
```

CSS: You may adjust the width and height to your liking

```
#rectangle {width: 300px; height: 20px; background-color: green;}
```